# how do lambda expressions work in c# when the variable isn't defined

Tags: c#, lambda

I always see arguments to functions in c# where the parameter is a lambda expression. However, I'm never sure how that is used in the function.

For example, here is an example of a function where the argument is a lambda:

```
var returnVal = foobar( x => Math.Pow(BackOffIncrementInSeconds, x));
```

How exactly would this work if I haven't actually defined `x`?

Comment: It depends on the definition of `foobar` and its expression argument

Comment: Side note: `x => Math.Pow(BackOffIncrementInSeconds, x)` is the same as `(double x) => Math.Pow(BackOffIncrementInSeconds, x)` if that makes you feel better that you "defining the x variable"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the definition of `foobar` and its expression argument

For example, look at the following potential definition of `foobar`

```
public double foobar(Expression<Func<double, double>> expression) {
    Func<double, double> function = expression.Compile();
    double value = 2D;
    return function(value);
}
```

*(note, the passed parameter can be replaced with any of the many alternative delegates. This is purely for demonstrative purposes)*

When invoked in your example

```
var returnVal = foobar(x => Math.Pow(BackOffIncrementInSeconds, x));
```

The value of `x` when invoked above would be `2.0`

The expression would not be able to be invoked without a defined variable.

Unless you own the function, you have no control of the variable passed to the expression. That is in the control of the calling function, which in this case is `foobar`

Comment: It can also just be `Func<>`, doesn't HAVE to be `Expression<Func<>>`

Comment: Yes, agreed. I stayed with Expression based on wording used by OP

Answer (score 0):

X doesn't represent anything in the context of the calling scope (the code you posted). It's a parameter to the lambda function when you call it.
It's the same as writing this:

```
private static double DoSomeWork(double X)
{
    Math.Pow(BackOffIncrementInSeconds, X);
}
```

And then calling this instead:
    `foobar(DoSomeWork)`;

Answer (score 0):

This **is** your variable to some extent:

```
x => Math.Pow(BackOffIncrementInSeconds, x)
```

foobar apparently takes an expression (or a Function).

For another example:

Usually one a List or IQueryable you might want to do something like:

```
var coolPeople = allPeople.Where(x => x.IsCool).ToList();
```

The Where method looks like this:

```
internal static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> where) {
            foreach (T t in enumerable) {
                if (where(t)) {
                    yield return t;
                }
            }
        }
```

Where you second parameter is a `Func<T, bool>`.

If you want to start writing these, look at [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) and [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the code you provided:

```
var returnVal = foobar( x => Math.Pow(BackOffIncrementInSeconds, x));
```

This code implies that you have a callable function (method, Action/Func or local function) with the name `foobar`. You have declared a variable `returnVal` that will have the same type as the return type of `foobar` (implied).

You are calling `foobar` and passing a `Func<Double, Double>` into it (assuming you are using the System `Math.Pow` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.8)

The `Func<T1, T2>` type is a block of code that takes in ONE argument of the leftmost generic type and returns ONE argument of the rightmost generic type (so happens in your example both are `double`).

The expectation of your code is that `foobar` will somehow call your `Func`.

An example might be:

```
static double foobar(Func<double, double> processor) {
   return processor((double)42);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example foobar is a function that takes a function as a parameter. A lambda expression is just a shorthand way of doing this.
For example you could have done this instead:

```
double MyFunction(int x)
{
    return Math.Pow(BackOffIncrementInSeconds, x);
}
```

and then:

```
var returnVal = foobar(MyFunction);
```

Of course in this case I guessed the signature of MyFunction since I can not see the signature of foobar based on the provided code.